# Change add node select field to show data from 2 different fields of other content type

Tags: nodes

I didn't know exactly how to ask this but the idea of what I need is very simple.

I have content type A with 2 fields: title and A2

Then I have another content type, B, with a node reference field (select box) that references title from node type A.

What I need is that the options in the select box are the concatenation of both title and A2 field.

Is this possible without coding my own module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Entity Reference module. It allows you to pull up information from one content type into another. Here is a super helpful tutorial of pretty much what you want to achieve so there is no need for me to provide detail explanation here. 
https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/getting-started-references-drupal

Comment: Thanks Dupls. That solved it. I used the Entity Reference module and created a view with the data I needed - title, A2 and a custom text field with the concatenation of both fields. In fact, this is a better way to do it because I can filter, sort and control what my reference field is showing.